# Android:Implementing 'Facebook like application' through facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am making an app in android and i am badly stuck in integrating facebook.I got authenticated and I am able to **post to wall** via my android app. But i don't know **how to make these three button working as depicted in image**

1. Friend Requests
2. Messages
3. Notifications

[image]

Any help regarding this will be appreciated..

Comment: why so.. I mean to say there is no library of facebook in which we can implement like this

Comment: Just read all the latest notifications from facebook and count the ones that the user didn't saw

Comment: i want to make all the above three , i mean is there some imported library for these..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was researching on your problem. I think you can achieve your aim by fql queries.

1. **Friend Requests**
   Table name: friend_request

   > SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me();
2. **Messages**
   Table name: mailbox_folder

   > SELECT name, unread_count, total_count FROM mailbox_folder WHERE
   >   folder_id = 0 and viewer_id = me()
3. **Notifications**
   Table Name: notification

   > SELECT notification_id, sender_id, title_html, body_html, href FROM notification 
   >   WHERE recipient_id= AND is_unread = 1 AND is_hidden = 0 AND created_time >

See [fql technical-guides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1 for help